# How to remove all PLMNs in EF FPLMN?

Tags: smartcard, gsm, apdu

When I want to remove a specific PLMN from EF FPLMN, I just replace it with FFFFFF according to Ts-131102 section 4.2.16. so for example if I want to remove 32f856 from EF FPLMN with the content 32f85632f857 in it, I just replace the desired PLMN with FFFFFF with the Update Binary command. so afterwards the content of EF FPLMN would look like this:
FFFFFF32f857.

Now I can remove all the PLMNs in EF one by one in this way, But is there anyway to remove all PLMNs at once? Or in general is there a way to remove all bytes of a transparent EF at once?

Answer (score 1):

You can of course update the whole transparent EF with the FF pattern using the UPDATE BINARY command.

Depending on on the size of the file and the supported data field length of your card / reader you may have to send more than one command and specify the offset from where on to update.

If the transparent EF is larger than 32 KByte, you have to use the UPDATE BINARY with odd INS code and give the offset and data to update in their respective data object.

If your card supports the ERASE BINARY command, you could use that instead.

[Have a look here for a description of the BINARY commands.](https://cardwerk.com/smart-card-standard-iso7816-4-section-6-basic-interindustry-commands/)